# Giving some particular style to my blog on my wordpress site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, blogs

I have a site made on WordPress and I'm displaying Wordpress posts on one of the pages. I need to do something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the post date is displaying on a div on the featured image. How can I manage to do that? Maybe there's a plugin to help me achieve this?

Comment: Did you created the theme? can you give more information?

Comment: This is my site:

http://hojalateriaelguante.agencialosnavegantes.cl/

I'm using a theme called "Divi". I modified the layout using css trying to replicate what is showed in the picture i included above, but still i don't know how to add the date on a div over the post's featured image. And no, the theme doesn't give me the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS can give you a startpoint:

```
.hentry {
    position: relative;
}
.hentry .published {
    display: block;
    background: #f6c506;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

You will need to change how post date is shown (Wordpress setting) and style a bit more. The pipe (|) is still on the post meta.

Note: i've tested on this page: http://hojalateriaelguante.agencialosnavegantes.cl/blog/

Comment: I think this pretty much solve my question. I'm gonna mark it like solved. Thanks a lot!